# Analytical integration of a composite Dirac delta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

From the well-known properties of the Dirac delta function

$ \delta(f(x)) = \sum_k \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|f'(x_k)|}
\qquad x_k = \text{zeros of }f(x) $,

$ \delta(f(x))=0
\qquad \qquad\qquad \text{if } f(x) \text{ has no zeros} $

it follows that

```
Assuming[f[y]!= 0, Integrate[DiracDelta[f[y]], {y, 0, Infinity}]]
```

should be zero. Instead, *Mathematica* is not able to compute it.

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function as a first reading).

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica works very carefully and correct in this case. One additionally needs to say that the function is real.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[f[x]], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> f[x] ∈ Reals && f[x]!= 0]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: How about asserting a positive $ f $?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ That works too because it $f(x)>0$ automatically implies that $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)\neq0$.